# NDSolve solving problem

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve for the function `y[x]` obeying the ODE:

$
\frac{x}{1 + x}y^{\prime\prime}(x) + \frac{2 x + 1}{(1 + x)^2} y^{\prime}(x) = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{y(x)}}
$

using NDSolve.

```
NDSolve[{(x/(1 + x)) D[y[x], {x, 2}] + ((2 x + 1)/(1 + x)^2) D[
      y[x], {x, 1}] == 1/(3 Sqrt[y[x]]), y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 0.02}]
```

but I got this error

```
NDSolve::ndnco: The number of constraints (1) (initial conditions) is not equal to the total differential order of the system (2).
```

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error?

Comment: You have second order ODE, but you only gave one IC. For numerical solver, it needs more one. (ps. the title of your question suggest it is a plotting problem, but there is no plotting issue here) (ps. actually the error message you get says the reason for the error :)

Comment: Also at 'x=0' the factor is front of `y''[x]` is null so this is a nasty ODE

Comment: This works for instance `NDSolve[{(x/(1 + x)) D[y[x], {x, 2}] + ((2 x + 1)/(1 + x)^2) D[
      y[x], {x, 1}] == 1/(3 Sqrt[y[x]]), y[1] == 1, 
  y'[1] == 0}, y, {x, 1, 2}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem numerically after mending two things

1) replace the 0 in x = 0 by a small quantity eps ( = 10^-5, say), i.e. write y[eps] == eps

2) add the second initial condition needed for an ODE of the second order, take e.g. y'(eps) = 1

The ODE is then easily NDSolved:

```
eps = 10^-5;

yy[x_] = y[x] /. 
  NDSolve[{((1 + 2 x) Derivative[1][y][x])/(1 + x)^2 + (
       x (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x])/(1 + x) == 1/(3 Sqrt[y[x]]), y[eps] == eps, 
     Derivative[1][y][eps] == 1}, y[x], {x, eps, 20}][[1]]

(*
Out[293]= InterpolatingFunction[{{0.00001,20.}},<>][x]
*)
```

You can now plot the function. Here you can even start at x = 0.
For comparison we have added the approximate solution `y = (3x/4)^(2/3)` close to `x = 0` obtained by inserting `y = A x^p` into the ODE and calculating A and p for `x->0`.

```
Plot[yy[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotLabel -> "Solution of ODE", 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y[x]"}]
(* 150407_Plot _ODE.jpg *)
```

[image]